# Disappeared drive from Windows

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, hard-drive

I have an SSD with Windows 10 installed on it, and 2 HDDs - drive D and F.
Yesterday I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on drive D.
After the installation, I booted into Windows and was surprised that drive D has disappeared from This PC.

How do I display it again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Windows is (without additional software) unable to display a typical Linux-formatted partition (extX, xfs) - this limitation does not apply the other way round.

You can try installing an ext4 IFS driver into WIndows, but YMMV.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: You google for such a driver, then install it according to its install instructions. I can't give you an exact URL, as I have stopped using Windows long ago. At that time it was http://www.fs-driver.org/ , but they don't support Windows 10. Start with https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Linux-Partitionen_unter_Windows/

Answer (score 1):

Windows can not recognize the Linux ext3 and ext4 partitions.